# How to rename a file with dired with the current file name as default?

Tags: dired

In the `macOS Finder`, I can rename a file or directory by pressing `RET` and the current value becomes the default for the new file name. This helps if I make a small change, such as adding a date at the beginning of the filename.

In Emacs with dired, I can rename with `R` but I don't have the previous value as the default, so I auto-complete it. This becomes dangerous if I make a mistake in the auto-completion and overwrite another file.

Can Emacs dired rename files incrementally as in the Finder?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>R</kbd> in dired queries the new file name in the minibuffer.
There you can access the current file name by pressing the <kbd>↓</kbd> button.

Note that this is a general convention when querying text input from the minibuffer. Pressing the <kbd>↓</kbd>-button gives you the default value(s), pressing the <kbd>↑</kbd>-button gives you the input history elements.

That way multiple default values become possible.

Comment: ↓ runs the command `next-history-element`, so does `M-n`.

Comment: @xuchunyang Yes, for me it is `next-line-or-history-element`. Nevertheless, what I said is true. Just try `(completing-read "Test: " '("first" "second" "third") nil nil nil nil '("DEF"))`. The arg `DEF` of `completing-read` is the list of default values. You get the default value(s) when you press ↓ right after running the command.

Comment: It's great to come here looking to learn something, and learn something else in addition to it.